# How to compare number of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to compare number of values in a dictionary.
Also, I want it to be sorted

```
dic = {x: {(1,2),(3,4)}, y:{(1,2)}}
```

I want to see like

```
[('x',2),('y',1)]
```

I was using lambda but I could not figure it out.

Comment: That is not valid Python code, as the `x` and `y` are not quoted.

Comment: Solving this does not require a lambda.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an input that looks like this:`dic={x:[a,b],y:[c]}`. Try this,

```
res=sorted([(x,len(dic[x])) for x in dic],key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and `dict.items`:

```
>>> dic = {"x": {(1, 2), (3, 4)}, "y": {(1, 2)}}
>>> [key: len(val) for key, val in dic.items()]
[('x', 2), ('y' ,1)]
```